# Buttons form one tkinter window appearing on the other tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

My buttons from my secondary window, are appearing on my primary login window, I'm not sure how to fix this, I have tried fixing this by altering the strings, but it has not seemed to work. Also, I cannot manage to get the window to delete itself after it has been used. I tried using the destroy function but that did not work either. This is the code for the login and its window and This is the code for the next screen and its buttons. (there might be some indentation issues however I had to manually press space 4 times infront of each line as it would not let me upload it

```
  #code for window
def main_screen():
  global screen
  screen = Tk()
  screen.geometry("300x250")
  screen.title("Login/Register")
  Label(text = "Login Or Register", bg = "red", width = "300", height = "2", font = ("Calibri", 13)).pack()
  Label(text = "").pack()
  Button(text = "Login", height = "2", width = "30", command = login).pack()
  Label(text = "").pack()
  Button(text = "Register",height = "2", width = "30", command = register).pack()

  screen.mainloop()

def week_A():
  os.startfile("WeekA.jpg")

def week_B():
  os.startfile("WeekB.jpg")

def time_table():
  global home_screen
  home_screen.geometry("300x250")
  home_screen.title("Timetable")
  Label(home_screen, text = "Which week do you want to check for?").pack()
  Label(home_screen,text = "").pack()
  Button(text = "Week A",height = "2", width = "30", command = week_A).pack()
  Label(home_screen,text = "").pack()
  Button(text = "Week B",height = "2", width = "30", command = week_B).pack()

def home_screen():
  global home_screen
  home_screen = Toplevel(screen)
  home_screen.geometry("400x300")
  home_screen.title("Home")
  Label(home_screen, text = "Welcome!").pack()
  Button(text = "Timetable", height = "3", width = "50", command = time_table).pack()
  Label(home_screen,text = "").pack()

  home_screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

Comment: *"there might be some indentation issues however I had to manually press space 4 times infront of each line as it would not let me upload it"* You can format the code like this: look at the [**help page**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: _"My buttons from my secondary window, are appearing on my primary login window"_ - you have several secondary windows. Which one are you asking about? Also, please remove all code that is unrelated to the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have updated the code to only show the actual tkinter windows. All the code i have written after the "main_screen" function is for the "home_screen" function, however it comes up on the "main_screen" window

Comment: The code references functions named `login` and `register` which aren't defined, and nothing calls the `home_screen` function. Also, it's a bad idea to have a global variable  and a function with the same name (`home_screen`)

Comment: @BryanOakley oh ok. Thank you